How do put a matte non-glossy finish on epoxy resin?
I poured some epoxy resin.
The epoxy resin dried to a high shine finish.
I want it to look chalky, matte, and have a non-gloss finish.
Is there a buffing wheel you can use on epoxy to make it dull and faded looking?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

If the space where the epoxy is at is easily accessible, use some 3000 grit wet sandpaper. That'll knock the sheen off of it without putting big gouges in it. Move the sandpaper in multiple directions when working the area. If it is a broad, relatively flat area, you could try your hand at putting the sandpaper on a random orbit sander.
